# Hibernate criteria using left join to filter results

Tags: java, hibernate

JSF application with hibernate

Is there a way to use a join to filter the results returned by criteria list?
Example: i have 2 tables.  orders and customers.

```
@Entity(name = "order")
public class Order
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String billingCustomerId;
    private String shippingCustomerId;
    private Date orderDate;
    ....
}

@Entity(name = "customer")
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String emailAddress

    ....
}
```

I need to return all orders for customers that are missing an email address and all orders that the `order.billingCustomerId = null` and  `order.shippingCustomerId = null`.

The customer could match on the `billingCustomerId` or `shippingCustomerId`.

The SQL I would use

```sql
select o.* from order as o
LEFT  join customer as c1 on o.billingCustomerId = c1.id
LEFT  join customer as c2 on o.shippingCustomerId= c2.id
where (o.billingCustomerId is null and o.shippingCustomerId is null) or 
(o.billingCustomerId is not null and c1.emailAddress is null) or
(o.shippingCustomerIdis not null and c2.emailAddress is null)
```

Hibernate Criteria

```
Criteria criteria1 = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("billingCustomerId"),
Restrictions.isNull("shippingCustomerId"));
List<Order> = criteria.list();
```

This will return the list of orders that billing /shipping customer = null.

How can i change the criteria to also include the orders for customers with missing email addresses?

```
Disjunction disjunciton = Restrictions.disjunction();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
disjunciton.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("billingCustomerId"),
        Restrictions.isNull("shippingCustomerId")));
disjunciton.add(...


                ...)
criteria.add(disjunciton);
List<Order> = criteria.list();
```

I have not been able to find examples of joining on a column, but only where the table have a common key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question: [Hibernate trouble getting composite key to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958048/hibernate-trouble-getting-composite-key-to-work) and discovered Hibernate can only create a join on columns that were created by relating 2 objects. I am going to add more to my answer to give more useful information but the best alternative you your case is to do a Session.createSQLQuery() using the query you showed above. Then before running the query put Query.addEntity(Order.class).addEntity(Customer.class). As long as your query returns the correct rows to fill out the Java objects correctly, Hibernate can populate them automatically. If that doesn't work you can still retrieve the data and populate it manually yourself.